# facing difficulty on implementing "groupBy" method in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-relations

I am trying to fetch data using groupBy method in laravel, but it's returning all data. what I am trying to get is

lets there are 2 tables

Table 1 : variants

```
id    variant
1     color
2     size
```

Table 2: product_variants

```
color   variant_id
red     1
yellow  1
red     1
sm      2
xl      2
lg      2
```

Now I want to fetch data so it returns as follow:

```
variant_table: {
  id:1,
  variant: color,
  variants: {
    variant_id: 1,
    color:red
  },
  {
    variant_id: 1,
    color:yellow
  }
},

{
  id:2,
  variant: size,
  variants: {
    variant_id: 2,
    color:sm
  },
  {
    variant_id: 2,
    color:lg
  },
  {
    variant_id: 2,
    color:xl
  }
}
```

But I am getting all variants instead of distincts grouped by variant_table id, My code:

```
$productVariants  = ProductVariant::with('productVariants')
    ->whereHas('productVariants',function ($q) {
        $q->groupBy('variant_id');
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: 1st you did not mentioned name of both tables, In the first table the column "color" have values other then color, like sm,xl,lg. please modify your question

Comment: I have modified the question, please check again

Comment: what is the relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let suppose the model of product_variants table is ProductVariant
let suppose  the model of variants table is Variant
let suppose the in model ProductVariant the relation function name is variant()

```
$product_variants = ProductVariant::with('variant')->groupBy('variant_id')->get();
```

try this `$product_variants = ProductVariant::with('variant')->get()->groupBy('variant_id');`
if it does not work than config\database.php -->  "mysql" array
Set 'strict' => false

Comment: I am getting this error `SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'assesment_test.product_variants.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `product_variants` group by `variant_id`)`

Comment: first remove ->groupBy('variant_id') from query and check if it works without grouping them by id.

Comment: change the place of get() with groupBy() in the query . if it does not work then Set 'strict' to false in Config\database.php for mysql array